# Searching in a ListFragment using LoaderEX

Tags: android, cursor, commonsware-cwac

I'm having a major block trying to search for data in my lists generated using Cursors from a prepopulated SQLite db.

I'm using the following libs:

- ActionBarSherlock.
- [SQLite Asset Helper](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper) (to ease the loading of data from my db).
- [LoaderEx](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-loaderex).

When I start my app, the list is empty and when I type letters on the SearchView, nothing is displayed. The query used works because before trying to implement the library all the data was displayed.

```
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.LoaderManager;
import android.support.v4.content.Loader;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockListFragment;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.Menu;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuInflater;
import com.actionbarsherlock.widget.SearchView;
import com.actionbarsherlock.widget.SearchView.OnQueryTextListener;
import com.commonsware.cwac.loaderex.acl.SQLiteCursorLoader;

import es.nirvash.android.mvptimer.adapters.MobListAdapter;
import es.nirvash.android.mvptimer.database.DataBaseManager;

public class FragMvp extends SherlockListFragment implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {

    private DataBaseManager dataBase;
    private MobListAdapter mAdapter;
    private SQLiteCursorLoader mloader;
    private String currentQuery = null;
    private final static int MVP_ID = 1100;

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);

        dataBase = new DataBaseManager(getSherlockActivity());

        Cursor cursor = dataBase.mobList("2");

        if (cursor != null) {
            mAdapter = new MobListAdapter(getActivity(), cursor, false);
            setListAdapter(mAdapter);
        }
        getLoaderManager().initLoader(MVP_ID, null, FragMvp.this);
    }

@Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search).getActionView();
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(queryListener);
    }

    final private OnQueryTextListener queryListener = new OnQueryTextListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(newText)) {
                currentQuery = "";
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Searching for: " + currentQuery + "...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                currentQuery = newText;
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Searching for: " + currentQuery + "...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            currentQuery = query;
            return false;
        }
    };

    @Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle bargs) {
        String query = 
        "SELECT mo._id, mo.sprite, mo.iName, mo.LVL, mo.HP, ra.Race, pr.Property, mo.Counter " +
        "FROM Mobs AS mo " +
        "JOIN Race AS ra ON (ra._id = mo.Race) " +
        "JOIN Property AS pr ON (pr._id = mo.Property) " +
        "WHERE mo.MobType = ? " +
        "AND mo.iName LIKE ? " +
        "ORDER BY mo.iName " +
        "ASC;";
        String like = "%" + currentQuery + "%";
        String[] args = { "2", like };

        mloader = new SQLiteCursorLoader(getActivity(), dataBase, query, args);

        return (mloader);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor cursor) {
        mAdapter.changeCursor(cursor);
        if (isResumed()) {
            setListShown(true);
        } else {
            setListShownNoAnimation(true);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
        mAdapter.changeCursor(null);
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Thank you in advance.

Comment: I have not experimented with using loaders and `SearchView` in combination. That being said, you are doing nothing to cause a new `Cursor` to be loaded. Just setting `currentQuery` to some value is not magically going to cause you to get a new `Cursor`.

Comment: But in `onCreateLoader`I build the arguments with the data from `currentQuery` and pass it to `SQLiteCursorLoader`, who should be creating the `Cursor`, right?

Comment: The first time, yes, when your fragment starts up and you call `initLoader()`. Then the user does a search and your code does nothing of significance, other than changing `currentQuery`. Just setting `currentQuery` to some value is not magically going to cause you to get a ***new*** `Cursor`.

Comment: Ooooh, I understand now. I should had put`restartLoader` inside `onQueryTextChange`, so everytime the letter changes the cursor gets updated! I'm goint go test that right now.

Comment: Yep! It's working now, finally! Thank you very much for the hints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to CommonsWare, I figured out that the putting the `initLoader()` method inside `onActivityCreated` was wrong because it was only called once.

Instead, I should put the `restartLoader()` method inside the funcion called everytime the `SearchView` gets updated, `onQueryTextChange`.

```
final private OnQueryTextListener queryListener = new OnQueryTextListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(newText)) {
            currentQuery = "";
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Searching for: " + currentQuery + "...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            currentQuery = newText;
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Searching for: " + currentQuery + "...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        **getLoaderManager().restartLoader(MVP_ID, null, FragMvp.this);**
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
        currentQuery = query;
        return false;
    }
};
```